# this.props.navigation.state.params is undefined

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

My code worked without problem with react navigation V3, but following an update to version 5.
I had a piece of code to get the name of the route of the active screen, but following an update to version V5, this.props.navigation.state.params is undefined.

this piece of code is no longer functional react navigation V5

```
const activeScreen = this.props.navigation.state.routes[
  this.props.navigation.state.index
].routeName;
```

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1):

For params, you need to use `useRoute` (or `this.props.route`)

```js
const params = useRoute().params
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/route-prop.html

For navigator's state, you need to use `useNavigationState`:

```js
const focusedRoute = useNavigationState(state => state.routes[state.index]):
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/use-navigation-state.html